# Getting failed on returning string from API to JSON AJAX POST in mvc Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

```
$("#modelchange").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStore")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Id: $("#modelchange").val()
        },
        success: function(storeName) {
            $('#storeName').text("Store : " + storeName);
        },
        error: function(ex) {
            alert('Failed to load store Value');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

API

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetStore(int Id)
{
    string storeName = db.AddInktoStores.Single(a => a.InkId == Id)).Store.StoreName;
    return storeName;
}
```

Above mentioned is a controller and JSON in my javascript.

I am trying to get Store Name but I keep getting throw into my error: function

Please Help!

Comment: What `error`???

Comment: Do you event hit the controller with AJAX call?

Comment: 'Failed to load store Value" @Satpal

Comment: Yes it hits controller gets the value in controller and return error in view alert @DejanDimčić

Comment: Debug your code. What is the error (use you browser tools - the Network tab to inspect it)

Comment: pass the data values as stated here data: {
                "Id": $("#modelchange").val()
            },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return data as:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetStore(int Id)
{
     string storeName = db.AddInktoStores.Single(a => a.InkId == Id)).Store.StoreName;
     return Json(storeName);
}
```